# Python 3.6 how to make a regular function work same way as lambda

Tags: python, function, lambda, list-comprehension

I'm a bit puzzled with converting following lambda function into a regular function:

```
my_fun = lambda x,y:[i(j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

where x is a list of types, say

```
types = [float,float,float]
```

and where y is a list of integer values, say:

```
values = [1,2,3]
```

so, basically my_fun() converts integers into floats. When I run it this way:

```
new_values = my_fun(types,values)
```

it returns a new list with floats.

Now when it comes to define a function in a regular way:

```
def my_fun(x,y):
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        i(j)
```

it stops working. I'm not putting return inside / outside of a loop as it will obviously return first / last instance once it hits it and not trying to assign a new list like:

```
def my_fun(x,y):
    new_vals = []
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
       new_vals.append(i(j))
    return new_vals
```

because in this case this function looks to overwhelmed to me.
Can someone please explain fundamental difference between lambda and regular function in my case, as it seems I am missing some simple basic knowledge about Python 3.6?

I thought it might have been for list-comprehension I'm using in my lambda but I couldn't explain it to myself.
Many thanks!

Comment: "*I'm not putting return inside / outside of a loop as it will obviously return first / last instance once it hits it*" <= This is not Perl. Without explicit return, your function returns `None`. There's no implicit "return value of last expression".

Comment: @dhke I was just thinking how to make this function make a multiple returns to produce a list of converted values but obviously my knowledge was not enough to make any sense of it.

Answer (score 3):

This seems more a misunderstanding about list comprehensions. You could express this as:

```
def my_fun(x,y):
    return [i(j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

The problem in your first example is you don't return anything. You could use [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) to give you an iterator.

```
def my_fun(x,y):
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        yield i(j)
```

Comment: does list-comprehension has some different features oppose to a simple for-loop? I mean it seems a bit veiled to me when I make a list-comprehension and pass it to an undeclared variable, the variable gets populated with a new list of values, e.g. `variable = [i(j) for i,j in zip(types,vals)]`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by veiled. Python assigns the newly created list to `variable`, in the background it still has to iterate through the list and create it.

Answer (score 1):

equivalent of this lambda

```
lambda x,y:[i(j) for i,j in zip(x,y)] #returns an array/list
```

is,

```
def myfun(x,y):
    return [i(j) for i, j in zip(x,y)]
```

or your last snippet.

below function

```
def my_fun(x,y):
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        i(j)
```

does not return anything.  it just passes `j` argument to `i` function and calls it. there is neither a declaration for an array, nor a set of procedures to store results on that array.